# Similar property names in ViewModel not binding in controller action method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently we updated our application from MVC3 to MVC4. In MVC4 we have discovered that having property names like `Studio` and `StudioExecutive` in our ViewModel will cause problems when posting. In the controller method we will always get `Studio = null` when `StudioExecutive` is being populated.

Here is an example of our issue and hope there is an answer for this problem.

Data Classes:

```
public class TestContact
{

    public List<TestContactItem> Studio { get; set; }
    public List<TestContactItem> StudioExecutive { get; set; }

    public TestContact()
    {
        Studio = new List<TestContactItem>();
        StudioExecutive = new List<TestContactItem>();
    }
}

public class TestContactItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Methods:

```
public ActionResult TestContactView()
{
    var vm = new TestContact();
    vm.Studio.Add(new TestContactItem(){Id=1, Name = "Studio Contact ID=1"});
    vm.StudioExecutive.Add(new TestContactItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Studio Exec Contact ID=2" });
    return View(vm);
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveTestContact(TestContact model)
{
    return Content("success");
}
```

View / JavaScript with Ajax POST:

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@model TestContact

<button type="button" onclick="SaveTestContact();">Click Here to Post</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
         globalTestModel = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    });

    function SaveTestContact() {
        // passing additional studio & studio executive parameter to controller because it was not mapping correctly to the server side viewmodel without it
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Test/SaveTestContact",
            data: JSON.stringify(globalTestModel),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In this example we are populating our object with at least one `Studio` and one `StudioExecutive` and render the view. When the button in the view is clicked, we POST the same object to the controller method but the ViewModel is not binding correctly the `Studio` property is set to null.

*Unfortunately I'm not able to post images I have a screenshot of the object showing that the `Studio` count was 0 and the `StudioExecutive` count was 1

We did put a breakpoint before the POST to make sure the serialization on the JavaScript was correct and the object was populated.

We have concluded that this has to do with the naming convention of the 2 properties one being a substring of the other. Any one who has encounter the same problem and can point us on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the **"complete answer"** to the question but I feel that this will give additional insight to the issue, that (I hope) will eventually lead to the "complete solution".

Say we have a single item in each of `Studio` and `StudioExecutive` fields as shown in the example of the OP, and do the following in `js`:

```
globalTestModel = '@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model))';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test/SaveTestContact",
    data: JSON.stringify(globalTestModel),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {

    }
});
```

The controller method will only receive `StudioExecutive` as already mentioned. Now if we do the same and build the object in js as shown below, we get the **same result**.

```
o = {
    Studio: [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Studio Contact ID=1',
    }],
    StudioExecutive: [{
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Studio Exec Contact ID=2',
    }]            
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test/SaveTestContact",
    data: JSON.stringify(o),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {

    }
});
```

Now here comes the interesting part. If we add another item to the `Studio` field and post the same way **we will get the same result**.

```
// Do this in the controller and do the same ajax post
public ActionResult TestContactView()
{
    var vm = new TestContact();
    vm.Studio.Add(new TestContactItem(){Id=1, Name = "Studio Contact ID=1"});
    vm.Studio.Add(new TestContactItem(){Id=3, Name = "Studio Contact ID=3"});
    vm.StudioExecutive.Add(new TestContactItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Studio Exec Contact ID=2" });
    return View(vm);
 }
```

But if we will build the object in `js` as shown below the controller will receive both the `Studio`, with 2 items, and the `StudioExecutive`, with one item.

```
o = {
    Studio: [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Studio Contact ID=1',
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Studio Contact ID=2',
    }],
    StudioExecutive: [{
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Studio Exec Contact ID=2',
    }]            
};
// then do the ajax post
```

### So what have we learned

This tells us two things:

1. There is something wrong with the default model binder in that it cannot bind two, or more, fields that starts with the same name
2. `JSON.stringify` can also **NOT** do it if there is only one item, but it **can** do it if there are more than one item in the field that has the shortest name (e.g. `Studio`)

Comment: i can see a pattern matching hash used during pre-compile (for efficiency) that has bugs. You've uncovered a blind corner of functionality that crosses multiple technologies.

Comment: wish I could. If I'm right, this is a problem under the covers. In fact, all the heavy lifting was on your end.